# Draw each string in list with a different tint color

Tags: c#, xna

So I have this code:

**EDIT:**

```
// Variables
private Dictionary<string, Color> menuEntries;
private Color fontColour;

// LoadContent()
fontColour = Color.White; // By default
menuEntries = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
menuEntries["SinglePlayer"] = Color.White;
menuEntries["MultiPlayer"] = Color.Gray;
menuEntries["Achievements"] = Color.White;
menuEntries["Options"] = Color.White;
menuEntries["Quit Game"] = Color.White;

// Draw()
/*for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.Count; i++)
{
    Vector2 fontOrigin = Game.gameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuItems[i]) / 2;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.gameFontLarge, menuItems[i], new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, (ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2) + 48 * i), fontColour, 0.0f, fontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
}*/

foreach (var entry in menuEntries)
{
    var text = entry.Key;
    var color = entry.Value;
    Vector2 fontOrigin = Game.gameFontLarge.MeasureString(entry.Key) / 2;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.gameFontLarge, entry.Key, new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, (ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2)), entry.Value, 0.0f, fontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
}
```

So how change the value of `fontColour` (by default is `Color.White`), to something like `Color.Gray`? If I wan one of the strings to be "greyed out" and feel like it's disabled? So basically I need a solution to how to draw each string with different color I specify somewhere in my code? Should I use a `Dictionary<string, Color>` instead of a `List<string>` and if so, how to iterate through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<string, Color>` sounds good to me.

```
foreach (var entry in menuItems)
{
   var text = entry.Key;
   var color = entry.Value;
   // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** As for the question in the comment, you can define variable outside the `foreach` and use it inside, like:

```
var y = ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2;
foreach (var entry in menuEntries)
{
    var text = entry.Key;
    var color = entry.Value;
    Vector2 fontOrigin = Game.gameFontLarge.MeasureString(entry.Key) / 2;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.gameFontLarge, entry.Key, new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, y), entry.Value, 0.0f, fontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
    y += 48;
}
```

Comment: Can you look at my code above, as it is at the moment. It draws each of the strings at the same coordinates since I used a `foreach` loop as you suggested, instead of a `for` loop I already had. Please take a look at the commented out loop in the `Draw()` method. Before, each of the strings would be drawn 48 pixels below its predecessor, but now they are on the same coordinates. Any suggestions?

Comment: I  have no more questions, that's just what I needed!